# Convert words to mobile numeric keypad sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a task to write a function that convert a word into mobile numeric keypad sequence (e.g: "test" - "83377778").

Numeric keypad looks like this:
[numeric keypad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFaIw.png)

The word is described by the sequence of numbers you clicked. To write the letter "B", click twice 2, letter "R" 3 times 7, etc.

My code:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [output, setOutput] = useState("");

  const str = [
    "2",
    "22",
    "222",
    "3",
    "33",
    "333",
    "4",
    "44",
    "444",
    "5",
    "55",
    "555",
    "6",
    "66",
    "666",
    "7",
    "77",
    "777",
    "7777",
    "8",
    "88",
    "888",
    "9",
    "99",
    "999",
    "9999",
  ];

  const printSequence = (arr, input) => {
    let output = "";
    let n = input.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (input[i] == " ") output = output + "0".charCodeAt(0);
      else {
        let position = input[i].charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0);
        output = output + arr[position];
      }
    }

    setOutput(output);
  };

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    printSequence(str, value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>convert</button>
      <p>result: {output}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately in result (for "test") I get `undefinedundefinedundefinedundefined`. Where's the mistake?

Comment: How do you type word "abc"?

Comment: why not create an object with the desired options: like `{"22": "B", "333": "R" ... }`?

Comment: @MichaelH "abc" - "2 22 222"

Comment: const str = ["2", "22", "222", ... ]; this array created by you, or given by tasker

Comment: @sathishk2030 created by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting undefined because the position you're checking for in the array `arr` doesn't exist for lowercased letters since you're subtracting it from `"A".charCodeAt(0)`. You can modify

```
let position = input[i].charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0);
```

to

```
let position = input[i].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0);
```

for your code to work.